# My App not loading Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using this code for load google map
private GoogleMap myMap;

```
if(myMap!=null){
            myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(getAddress(latitude, longitude)));
            Location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(Location).zoom(15) 
                    .bearing(90) // Sets the orientation of the camera to
                    .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            // myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15));
            }
```

but map is not loading and occurring this issue

[image]

Comment: Google map need play services in your device.

Comment: The error is self explanatory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23265214/1318946

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23450257/1318946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the latest Google play services in your phone/tab/emulator before running the app.

[For google play on emulator.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11154222/2219600)

Comment: Correct, this is installable via the Google Play store, provided the store is available on the tablet.

Comment: @amalBit now i have installed google play service in my mobile. but google map is display empty screen.

Comment: Empty google map means that you have done every thing right and just a few things to check. 1. Do you have network?. 2. Your google API key might not be registered properly.